# How do i deal with this multiple parameters issue in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I've tried to write a query using mapper of mabatisbut can't make it so far

This is my code

```
String SQL_SELECTPAGE = "select b.writer, b.title, b.topicdate, b.lecturekey, b.tcontent" +
        "from (select rownum rn, a.* from (select * from topics WHERE LECTUREKEY = #{lid}" +
        "order by topicdate desc) a) b" +
        "where rn between #{c.start} and #{c.end}";

@Select(SQL_SELECTPAGE)
List<Topics> selectPage(@Param("lid") String lid, @Param("c") PaginationCriteria c);
```

`PaginationCriteria` has start and end attribute.

Below is HTTP Status 500 error message. I think parameter couldn't pass

> ... WHERE LECTUREKEY = ?order by topicdate desc) a) bwhere rn between ? and ?   > ### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936:

I'd be glad if someone can help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a JDBC bind parameter for the row number clause.  In MyBatis, anything specified with `#{...}` is a bind parameter.  Anything you specify as `${...}` is, basically, string substitution which should work here.

So rewrite your where clause like this `where rn between ${c.start} and ${c.end}`

Comment: thank you for answer. i solved it. i had to check space in query